# matching a string between special characters in JAVA

Tags: java, character, matching

I want to match n number of characters between a "<" and ">" characters. For example, 
I want to be able to match `<a href = "image1.jpg">` or 
`<a href = " http://www.learnmore.com/&gt;` essentially with the same pattern. This is because, the strings I  receive might have n number of characters between the special characters. Once I match the pattern which includes the special characters, I will replace it with a blank space(which I am able to do currently---the replacing part.). I need help with the matching part only.

Comment: what have you done so far? can you post it so we can see it?

Comment: \"[^\"]* might work, but parsing HTML with regexp is not robust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory ["don't try to parse HTML with regex" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regular expression

```
(&lt;|<)(.*?)(&gt;|>)
```

to match against your string (assuming the `&gt;` was not a formatting error in your question but the actual content in the string).

Comment: I am trying to replace HTML tags with a blank space. If I hard code the HTML tag, I can replace and get the tag, but I am trying to match any tag and so the question on the forum. @Howard, I tried your expression, but it did not work. The &gt; was a formatting error. It should be < or >.

Answer (score 0):

First replace `&gt;` with `>` and `&lt;` with `<`. Then do your pattern matching as usual using regex or whatever.